# sibling selector CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a page with  the following structure. I want to apply the background color for each "componet-4" but want to apply different color only for the first element "componet-4".
How to point out the first element from others.I have to support IE7 and IE8 also . 
I can not use Javascript ,I want to acheive it by using css ,is it possible?? Please advice me.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div id="component-1">

 <div class="component-2">
    <div class="component-3">
     <div class="component-4">  
    </div>
    </div>    
  </div>


  <div class="component-2">
    <div class="component-3">
     <div class="component-4">  
    </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <div class="component-2">
    <div class="component-3">
     <div class="component-4">  
    </div>
    </div>    
  </div>  

</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Please advice me..

Comment: use `.component-1>.component-2 .component-4`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Thank you for ur comment but i want to point out the first component-4 from other component-4..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use pseudo class `first-child`

```
.component-4{
  background:red
}
.component-2:first-child .component-4{
  background:green
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oQigoluL/3/)**

Comment: thank you for your answer,Will it work on IE7 and IE8?

Comment: Did you test the demo??

Comment: @rightPath `:first-child` is supported since IE7. It'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I don't have IE 7 or 8, but I did test it using an IE emulator.

here is an example of what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/ffVW3/

You have an element div with id `component-1` and inside it multiple divs with repeating classes `component-2, component-3 and component-4`

You can style these elements individually using classes as in the example. the trick to just change the background color for first div (or any div) is to find out the level of the div you need to change and apply CSS Pseudo class ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)) ([W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)) ([CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/)) to it.

Its fairly simple. The following code: (1)

```
.component-2 {
    background: red;
}
```

applies all elements with class `component-2` with a red background.

and the following code: (2)

```
.component-4{
    background: pink;
}
```

applies all elements with class `component-4` with a pink background. According to your code, another way of writing the above code would be: (3)

```
.component-2 .component-4{
    background: pink;
}
```

applies all elements with class `component-4` within `component-2` with a pink background.

We know that you have multiple `component-2`, `component-3` and `component-4` classes in your code.

Following the hierarchy, `#component-1` has multiple `component-2` which has `component-3` which has `component-4` so if we omit `#component-1` we have 3 divs with classes `component-2` on same level of hierarchy.

Pseudo Selector has selectors for various cases (first child, last child, nth-child, even, odd, etc.). For your code, you know that you need to change the first element's color.

so, in order to change the first `component-4` color, we need to traverse upward the tree to find the repeating node. which in this case is `component-2`. The correct way to select that element to add css rules using pseudo class is (4)

```
.component-2:first-child{
    /* css rules here */
}
```

now that we know that whatever is written in side that container applies to the first div of classname `component-2`, lets apply that class selector to one of the above mentioned selector as mentioned in (3)

```
.component-2:first-child .component-4{
    /* css rules here */
}
```

This rule specifies that ONLY the first div with class `component-2`'s child with class name `component-4` should have the css rules applied to it.

Thus, by doing so, you will achieve your result.

You can play around by changing the pseudo class to `:last-child` or `:nth-child(2)` to see differences what pseudo classes can make.

I know that this is a a long post for a simple answer, but I hope that you will learn something out of this.

cheers!